# const reference and creating copy

Tags: c++

(Newbie learning c++ with existing codebase)
Consider the following snippet:

```
class Filter
{
    ...
public:
    Filter();
    int addFilter(gFilter &filterDesc);
    …
};

class gFilter 
{
  public:
  ….
  inline const RangeOfUInt&  getProto() const
  {
       return proto; 
  }
  private:
     …
     RangeOfUInt   proto;
     …
};

typedef struct
{
    ValueType  type;
    uint32_t   value1;
    uint32_t   value2;
} UIntRange;

typedef std::list<UIntRange> RangeOfUInt;
…

const RangeOfUInt protos = filterDesc.getProto();   //  XXX
```

So in this example, getProto() returns const reference and will create a copy for 'protos' ?

Comment: Not just a copy; it is also a **`const`** copy. So you cannot modify it, invoke any non-const members from it, or pass it as a non-const parameter to any function. If you want a modifiable copy, lose the `const` decl on `protos`.

Comment: You may find the answer here, but I would also suggest you to check it yourself by debugging or just adding in constructor/copy constructor/destructors and putting in some logging such as std::out<<"ClassName Ctor called" etc. Better to check with optimization turned off.

Comment: In C++ it's preferred to write `struct UIntRange { ... };` rather than `typedef struct { ... } UIntRange;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically it will create a copy of the protos, 'typically' because compiler might add some optimizations depending on the specific code paths, but while coding we need not worry about that. Since you are looking only for a reference the following change would avoid the copy.

```
const RangeOfUInt& protos = filterDesc.getProto(); //Make the return variable a reference
```

Comment: In the OP's code initializing the variable `protos` from an lvalue reference must make a copy, the compiler is not allowed to optimize that away. (Copy elision aka RVO is not allowed there.)

Comment: Thanks everybody for valuable responses. I don't quite understand the suggestion 'const RangeofUInt& protos = ..', since getProto() already returns a 'const reference' and on left side we do reference of reference? How does this work anyway?

Comment: No the function returns a reference, so you are creating a variable that matches the exact type of the return type in this case. const A& x = f();    where defined is  const A& f() {}   in this case the function is returning a const reference from it's private member you are just creating a name 'x' in this case for it. Make sense?

Comment: @Mark, no, `const RangeofUInt& protos = ..` does not create a reference to a reference, it creates a reference to a `const RangeofUInt`, that's what `const RangeofUInt&` means!  You can bind more than one reference to the same object.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you are exactly right. `protos` is a copy made from the reference returned from `getProto`. (The caller creates the copy, `getProto` doesn't.)

Answer (score 0):

I think if you want a const reference then keep the method as is change and your call as noted by @jayadev to be `const RangeOfUInt& protos = filterDesc.getProto();`  If you want to modify a copy, then have a method call that just returns a copy. If you are using c++11 most items ( not sure what ValueType is ) seem move constructable and with copy value optimization you will not lose performance it will get constructed directly into the new object.  ( see NVRO )

```
RangeOfUInt protos = filterDesc.getProto();

class gFilter 
{
  public:
  ….
  inline RangeOfUInt  getProto()
  {
       return proto; 
  }
  private:
     …
     RangeOfUInt   proto;
     …
};
```

Comment: _"If you want to modify a copy, then have a method call that just returns a copy."_ Not necessary, the OP's code is fine. `getProto()` returns by reference, so callers who don't need a copy don't have to make one, but callers who want a copy can do so.

Comment: Yes, but it was a const reference and therefore a const copy. I was referring to if he wanted a copy of a modifiable version.

Comment: What do you mean "a const copy"?  You don't need to change the member function signature to make a modifiable copy

Comment: const RangeOfUInt protos = filterDesc.getProto();   //  XXX  is what he had which is what I meant by const copy. The member signature doesn't need to change I know, I was saying if he didn't need a reference and just wanted a copy he could just have it return a copy.

Comment: And as I said in the first comment above, that change is not useful. Either you copy the object inside `getProto` or the caller copies it outside, it makes no difference, except that returning a reference allows callers to decide **not** to copy if they don't want to. Returning a value removes that choice from the caller.